# trying to call a named function with async javascript then

Tags: javascript, d3.js, async-await

I am loading data from a csv file with d3.csv(). I am trying to call a named function after returning the data, but this does not seem to work. It gives me the following error:

*Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access 'driving' before initialization*

```
let driving = d3.csv("./driving.csv").then( ConnectedScatterplot(driving, {
    x: d => d.miles,
    y: d => d.gas,
    title: d => d.year,
    orient: d => d.side,
    yFormat: ".2f",
    xLabel: "Miles driven (per capita per year) →",
    yLabel: "↑ Price of gas (per gallon, adjusted average $)",
    width:600,
    height: 720,
    duration: 5000 // for the intro animation; 0 to disable
  })) ;
```

if I do the following:

```
let driving = d3.csv("./driving.csv").then(function (driving) { ConnectedScatterplot(driving, {
```

It doesn't error and has 'driving' available, but it also doesn't do what I want, which is call ConnectedScatterplot with the parameters.

Comment: I don't know d3.csv, so can't help with that, but to find out what it actually produces you might simplify the code to `d3.csv("./driving.csv").then(data => console.log(data));` and look at the results. Or try doing `console.table(data)` instead of `console.log(data)` to see the details of the object. If running in a browser, then open the Dev Tools using F12 before any of this.

Answer (score 0):

It seems `d3.csv()` returns a Promise, then we have 2 ways to handle the result of the csv function:

As you did, just call `ConnectedScatterplot` in then block:

```
d3.csv("./driving.csv").then((driving) => { // let driving is redundant
    ConnectedScatterplot(driving, {...});
})
```

If you are inside an async function, you can use `await` syntax:

```
(async () => { // async function
    const driving = await d3.csv("./driving.csv"); // await
    ConnectedScatterplot(driving, {...});
})();
```